# Making offset to polyline using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, line

Is there a way to make an offset to a polyline in ArcGIS?
i.e. something like the command "Offset" from AutoCAD.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9A8CyoAMnjU

I can't use the Buffer tool because I need to be able to calculate the length.

Also the "New polyline" has to retain the attributes of the original polyline.

Comment: You can trace with an offset or copy parallel (delete the one you don't want) - both are in the standard edit tools.

Comment: Try copy parallel in editing session.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @MichaelMiles-Stimson:

*You can trace with an offset or copy parallel (delete the one you don't want) - both are in the standard edit tools.*

To retain the attributes of the original line select both lines and use the Attribute window to Copy Attributes of the original line then Paste Attributes onto the new line.